# How to create a button with 'save as' functionality in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a button in react js that works similar to 'save as' so that the user could select the filetype and location to be saved in the pc. I will be getting the a file from the server and want that file to be saved in a particular location. Please suggest me a solution for it.

What is the best possible way for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use those APIs in Google Chrome and MS Edge browser.

[showSaveFilePicker doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showSaveFilePicker)

```
window.showSaveFilePicker()
```

[Ponyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-file-system-adapter) for showDirectoryPicker, showOpenFilePicker and showSaveFilePicker, with fallbacks to regular input elements

Comment: api that supports all browers?

Comment: Added link to npm ponyfill